# Live server is not auto reload when i hit save on my Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

Someday in the past, I had this problem because my folder is .something it starts with the "." the live server is not working. But now, my folder isn't like that but the Live Server isn't working right again when I hit save on my vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure meta charset is "UTF-8" in the head.

Answer (score 0):

There’s one thing that resolves the issue.

- Open settings.
- Search for ‘autosave’.
- Set it to ‘afterDelay’.
- Just below that, set the AutoSaveDelay to anything very less like 5 (I have set it to 1)
- Now search for ‘Wait’ in settings.
- In LiveServer > Settings:Wait, set the value very low (e.g. 3). This should help regardless of platforms

Answer (score 0):

I use live-server on sublime text Ubuntu and I noticed that my saves is not committing to the auto save in the browser.

So what I noticed was that when I open the files individually but not as a folder the problem was solved. I hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to save a file that was not fully HTML.

I wrapped my code with proper HTML structure and now its working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- YOUR CODE -->
</body>
</html>
```